# Normal derivative of the Green function on the boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function, poissons-equation

In Lawrence C Evans' *Partial Differential Equations*, Chapter 2, he proves by construction that the representation formula for the solution to Poisson's equation with initial values:

$$\begin{cases} 
-\Delta u = f & \text{in }U,\\
\phantom{-\Delta}u = g & \text{on }\partial U.\end{cases}$$

using Green's functions is given by

$$u(x) = -\int_{\partial U} g(y) \frac{\partial}{\partial \nu} G(x,y)dS(y) - \int_{U}f(y)G(x,y)dy.$$

He then proceeds to say that by fixing $x \in U$, we may symbolically write

$$\begin{cases}
-\Delta G = \delta_x & \text{in } U,\\
\phantom{-\Delta}G = 0& \text{on }\partial U.
\end{cases}$$

Doesn't plugging this set of equations into the representation make the first term identically zero? As in, since the first integral is over the boundary of $U$, isn't $G$ zero there, and hence its normal derivative as well?

Comment: Well, $f(x) = 0$ does not imply that $f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: Perhaps you should compare with the explicit formula available for the ball. Specifically for your reasoning you can compare with $1-|x|$ which vanishes on the unit sphere but has normal derivative equal to $x$ at $x$

Comment: Sorry the normal derivative is 1, the gradient is $x$ which happens to be the normal vector